# How to create a column with information from other columns

Tags: r, for-loop

Not able to create the column as I want. It consist in using the previous third value of the flow column, for each new value of the event column.

I tried to approach this problem by using for loops but can't exactly replicate what I want. I'm close but not there.

just to recreate the example I generated the following data frame

```
flow<- c(40, 39, 38, 37, 50, 49, 46, 44, 60, 55, 40, 70, 80, 75, 90, 88, 86, 100, 120, 118)
event<- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,8)
a<- data.frame(flow, event)

for (j in seq(1, length(a$event))) {
  if (a$event[j] <= 1){ 
   a$BF[a$event==j]<- NA}                  
else{ 
 if (a$event[j] == a$event[j-1]){
  a$BF[a$event==j]<- a$flow[j-3]
  } else{
  a$BF[j]<- a$flow[j-3] }
 }
}

I expected to generate a column called "BF" to be like this:
    flow event BF
1    40     1  NA
2    39     1  NA
3    38     1  NA
4    37     1  NA
5    50     2  39
6    49     2  39
7    46     2  39
8    44     2  39
9    60     3  49
10   55     3  49
11   40     3  49
12   70     4  60
13   80     5  55
14   75     5  55
15   90     6  70
16   88     6  70
17   86     6  70
18  100     7  90
19  120     8  88
20  118     8  88
```

The error that I am obtaining with the previous code is that is not duplicating the values properly that match with the "event" column. (It should be as it is shown in the table).

Comment: Little hard to understand the logic. Maybe be more clear about how you're obtaining the new value. For example,  where does the value for row 13 come from? Shouldn't it just be 70?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear, the value from the row 13 for "bf" come from the previous 3rd value of the flow (value of flow for row 10), and so on for all the "bf" column. Other example is the row 5. The value of bf for that row is the 3rd previous value of the flow ( flow row 2 = 39).

Comment: When there is a change in the number of the "event" column, a new value for the "BF" column should start (which is going to be the value of the previous third row
for the "flow" column). This "BF" value should be the same for the "event" column until there is a change in the "event" column and then we search for a new value of "BF" by looking again for the previous 3rd row of the "flow" column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to get the output with `tidyverse`. This breaks your problem up into two pieces. There is likely something more succinct out there:

```
library(tidyverse)
critical_info <- a %>% 
  mutate(previous = lag(flow, 3)) %>% #find the previous flow number for each
  group_by(event) %>% 
  mutate(subevent = row_number()) %>% #to knew each subevent within an event
  filter(subevent == 1) %>% #filter out unimportant rows
  rename(BF = previous) %>% #rename the column
  select(event, BF) # get the right stuff

a %>% 
  left_join(critical_info, by ="event")
```

Answer (score 2):

More Tidy-er solution will be:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
 mutate(BF = ifelse(event<=1,NA,row_number()-3)) %>% 
 group_by(event) %>%
 mutate(BF = BF[1]) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(BF = a[BF,]$flow)

# A tibble: 20 x 3
    flow event    BF
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    40     1    NA
 2    39     1    NA
 3    38     1    NA
 4    37     1    NA
 5    50     2    39
 6    49     2    39
 7    46     2    39
 8    44     2    39
 9    60     3    49
10    55     3    49
11    40     3    49
12    70     4    60
13    80     5    55
14    75     5    55
15    90     6    70
16    88     6    70
17    86     6    70
18   100     7    90
19   120     8    88
20   118     8    88
```